# For $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ prove that $\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x(\cos x-\sin x)}>8$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> For $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ prove that
>   $$\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x(\cos x-\sin x)}>8$$

I am trying to use the following  for x $\in$ (0,$\frac{\pi}{4}$)

Cos x $\in$ ($\frac{1}{√2}$,1)

(sinx)^2 $\in$ (0,$\frac{1}{2}$)

(cosx-sinx) $\in (0,1)$

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vzcya6t4fb

Comment: [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), why not use mathjax correctly?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846161/if-x-in-left0-frac-pi4-right-then-frac-cos-x-sin2-x-cos-x-si/1846531#1846531

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try. We have $$\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x (\cos x - \sin x)} = \frac{1+\tan^2 x}{\tan^2 x(1-\tan x)}.$$

Note that $0 < x < \dfrac{\pi}{4}$, so $0 < \tan x < 1$,

$$\tan x(1-\tan x) \leq \frac{1}{4}(\tan x + 1-\tan x)^2 = \frac{1}{4}.$$

So we have $$\text{LHS} \geq 4\frac{1+\tan^2x}{\tan x} \geq 8.$$

The equality happens when $\tan x = \dfrac{1}{2}$ for first and $\tan x = 1$ for second, so $\text{LHS} > 8$.

Comment: can you explain the step 
$$\tan x(1-\tan x) \leq \frac{1}{4}(\tan x + 1-\tan x)^2 = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: It is simple: $(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$ with $a, b \geq 0$.